# Run-time manipulation of ValueListEditor rows and values in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I would like the user to be presented with the following options:

1. Do something?  The answer to this can be Yes or No
2. How many times?  This can be 100, 500, or 1000
3. Do you want a summary?  Again, yes or no.

To do this, I have created a form on which I placed a ValueListEditor with the first columns called Option (in this column I write the questions) and the second column called Selection (which will be Yes/No, 100/500/1000 and Yes/No, respectively).

No obviously, rows 2 and 3 make sense only if the user chooses "yes" in row #1.  So I would like to create rows 2 and 3 and provide the corresponding options only if the user has chosen Yes for Row 1.

I have written the following code for this, but it is clearly wrong.  By the way, I am new to programming in general, and am finding it really difficult to find a decent book on Delphi.  The problem is worsened by the fact that nobody else does any programming of any kind where I am, and so it can get very frustrating - and time-consuming (it took me the better part of a full day yesterday to come up with the following code!  I did not even know about ValueListEditor; as I was wading through the strangely organized Tool palette, it looked promising, and so I used it.).  Any pointers?

Here is my code (and thanks very much):

```
procedure TfrmDoSomething.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: integer;
  FirstItemProp, SecondItemProp, ThirdItemProp: TItemProp;
begin
  //add first row
  ValueListEditor1.InsertRow('Do something?', '', True);
  FirstItemProp := TItemProp.Create(ValueListEditor1);
  FirstItemProp.PickList.Add('Yes');
  FirstItemProp.PickList.Add('No');
  ValueListEditor1.ItemProps[0] := FirstItemProp;


//now add the subsequent two rows only if the value for Row#1 is Yes
  if (ValueListEditor1.ItemProps[0] = FirstItemProp.PickList[0]) then
    begin
      ValueListEditor1.InsertRow('Number of times', '', True);
      SecondItemProp := TItemProp.Create(ValueListEditor1);
      SecondItemProp.PickList.Add('100');
      SecondItemProp.PickList.Add('500');
      SecondItemProp.PickList.Add('1000');
      ValueListEditor1.ItemProps[1] := SecondItemProp;

      ValueListEditor1.InsertRow('Summary?', '', True);
      ThirdItemProp := TItemProp.Create(ValueListEditor1);
      ThirdItemProp.PickList.Add('Yes');
      ThirdItemProp.PickList.Add('No');
      ValueListEditor1.ItemProps[2] := ThirdItemProp;
    end;

end;
```

@KenWhite, thank you.  Based on your suggestion of using a ComboBox, I wrote the following code.  I guess my problem now is that I am using the wrong event for the CB.  My CB is programmatically created fine at run time (By the way, CB1 is declared globally).  however, when "yes" is selected, it does not go the second procedure "OnChange", which leads me to think that OnChange is the wrong event. I also tried OnClick and a few more - to no avail.  Also, the ShowMessage part in the second procedure is only to test if my choice of event was correct.  i will later have to write code to create the other two combo boxes.  Thanks.

```
procedure TfrmCBDoSomething.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Label1: TLabel;
begin
  Label1 := TLabel.Create(Self);
  Label1.Align := alLeft;
  CB1 := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  CB1.Parent := Self;
  CB1.Align := alRight;

  Label1.Caption := 'Do Something?';
  Label1.Parent := Self;
  CB1.AddItem('Yes', nil);
  CB1.AddItem('No', nil);
end;


procedure TfrmCBTry.CB1OnChange(Sender: TObject);

begin
  if (CB1.Text = 'Yes') then ShowMessage('Got it!!');
  if (CB1.ItemIndex = 0) then ShowMessage('Got it!!');
  if (Cb1.Items.IndexOf('Yes') = 0) then ShowMessage('Got it!!')
end;
```

Comment: You're doing all this in one go (FormCreate event). You should split this code in two parts: one part where you create first item, and other part where you create next two items in VLE. First part should be in FormCreate(), but the second part of the code should be in some event that gets called when Yes/No PickList value is changed, SetEditText() I guess.

Comment: @User1505202 These general rules will get you going: create your objects at design time, or if you have to do it at run-time, in the FormCreate. For the rest, let the event handlers of your objects do the work.

Comment: @User1505202 Practically any 'old' book with a generic 'Delphi programming' title will do. These books were often written not just for the beginner in Delphi, but for the beginning programmer as well.

Comment: Thanks both of you (it doesn't allow me to specify two names), especially for your prompt replies.  I will try to do what you suggest.  I will try the SetEditText event, but I doubt if the way I refer to the value for the first row is correct.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the right control for the task

Comment: @David, no it does not.  I am trying StringGrid, but I can't seem to place a drop-down for my second-column cells (which I did with vle).  Basically, I want a two-column table, with the first column having fixed values and the second that the user chooses from a drop-down list.  I would like to start with one row and depending on if the user chooses "Yes" for the question on this row, I would like to add more rows with their own drop-down lists.  And finally, I would like to capture all the user-choices by a Save button.  I have seen applications that do exactly this, but I don't know how to.

Comment: It shouldn't be a ValueListEditor *or* a TStringGrid, IMNO. It should be a form (or frame) with three ComboBoxes, the first containing your initial question and "Yes" and "No" as the Items. Based on the initial value you want, you set the ItemIndex and enable or disable the second and third ComboBoxes when you display the form/frame. If the user chooses "Yes", you enable the 2nd & 3rd ComboBoxes to allow the user to set those options; if they choose "No" you disable those ComboBoxes. Much easier to code.

Comment: Exactly. Value list editor is not cut out for scenarios where availability changes due to setting of other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, and using `TComboBox` (and presuming your question is about the VCL, as you mentioned `TValueListEditor` and gave no Delphi version):

You need to change the way you're adding items, and then assign the `OnChange` event in your code.

```
procedure TfrmCBDoSomething.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Label1: TLabel;
begin
  Label1 := TLabel.Create(Self);
  Label1.Align := alLeft;
  CB1 := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  CB1.Parent := Self;
  CB1.Align := alRight;
  CB1.Sorted := False;   // Keep order of items entered

  Label1.Caption := 'Do Something?';
  Label1.Parent := Self;
  CB1.Items.Add('Yes');
  CB1.Items.Add('No');
  // Assign the event handler
  CBI.OnChange := CB1OnChange;

  CB2 := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  CB2.Parent := Self;
  CB2.Items.Add('100');
  CB2.Items.Add('200');
  CB2.Items.Add('500');
  // Position CB2 and add label for second set of options
  // Repeat with CB3 for third set of options
end;

procedure TfrmCBTry.CB1OnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Enable both CB2 and CB3 if CB1 is 'Yes'
  CB2.Enabled := (CB1.ItemIndex = 0);  // Yes selected
  CB3.Enabled := (CB1.ItemIndex = 0);  
end;
```

I'm not sure why you're doing all of the above at runtime. This could easily be done in the form designer by just dropping three labels and three comboboxes on a form and setting their properties visually or in the Object Inspector (in the case of the `Items` or `OnChange` event, which you would complete the shell of by double-clicking it in the Object Inspector's events tab - that would also assign it to the combobox automatically).

(For future refrence: You should probably have just deleted your original question and asked a new one about TComboBox, or (since you'd received no answers) simply removed the original content of this one and used the info from your edit - AKA second question - as the content instead, so that the question was clear. I've answered only the second question, because it's the only one that has a reasonable answer.)

Comment: Thanks, @Ken.  Your second suggestions turned out to be the best 9and the only one that worked, actually).  Not quite sure how to select part 2 of your answer as the best, and so I'll select the entire answer as the best.  Thank again!

Comment: They both work. :-) I can't tell you why it didn't work for you, because you didn't define "didn't work". You probably didn't declare your `CB1OnChange` in the form's declaration. No matter, as long as you got it working.

Comment: You're probably right, @Ken.  Not sure if I did or not.  I now have the problem of writing an if statement to find out it a particular procedure has executed (in another unit).  I have added it to the uses in the current unit and say "if Unit2.SomeProcedure then" but it is asking for parameters.  So I tried "if Unit2.SomeProcedure(Sender) then" but is says this can be used only for class methods.  Been looking for help online and in books but not even sure what search terms to use!

Comment: Procedures don't return results. Functions do. You need to change your procedure to a function, and have it return a Boolean that indicates success or failure. Please don't use comments here asking for a tutorial. :-) This isn't a chat room or discussion group. A Google search for "Delphi tutorial" or "tutorial Delphi" will turn up several good sites that should get you started.